# How many items in a stack after some order of operations?

Tags: java, stack

In class we got a challenge problem to try out and I am just trying to figure out the best way to go about solving it. The question is, "An initially empty stack performs(in some order) 18 push operations, 8 peek operations, and 12 pop operations. 3 of the peek and 5 pop return null. How many items are in the stack after the operations are complete".

Honestly right now, I can only think of guessing and checking scenarios but there has to be a better way. I am just learning about this stuff so there is probably a simple way to do this I am just not knowledged enough haha. Thank you for any help you can offer :)

Comment: This is not about programming, more on the math side.

Comment: Two hints: (1) Peek doesn't remove an element and (2) if a pop operation returns null that means the stack was empty.

Comment: I mean it was in ComS class so I just figured I would ask. Wasn't sure where else to ask. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `pop` operation tries to remove an item from the stack. It may succeed and actually remove the item. Or it may fail (because the stack is empty) and not modify the stack. Failure is indicated by `null`.

You do 12 `pop` operations, of which 5 return null. That means 12-5 = 7 items were actually removed from the stack.

You know how many items were pushed to the stack, and now you know how many items were removed. It should be easy to calculate how many are left. The number of `peek` operations is a red herring: peek does not modify the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Since 5 pop operations return null there are 7 pop operations that have been made => 11 elements, peek only sees the element on top of the stack doesnt change it